# Plot characteristics of a PDE

Tags: plot

In [this answer on MathSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1542282/545914) there are plots of a the solutions of the Burgers equation along certain characteristics, which is different from a slope field.

Since the answer's author has left the site, I want to ask how to recreate such plots here.

Comment: Right now this question is both unclear and a just-do-it-for-me question. Why are you asking on this site? (Where is the connection to (La)TeX?) What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Please ask a _specific_ question for a _single_ problem.

Comment: Ok, let me reformulate: given a pde and the equation for the characteristics, what is an efficient way to plot the characteristics like in the answer linked? Is there a a special package or any premade i.e. tikz-code?

Comment: Well, sure. You can use `pgfplots` or the (less extensive) `datavisualization` library for plotting. If you want to do any numerical analysis of your PDE though, TeX is _not_ the right tool to use. Again, why do you want to do this with TeX in the first place?

Comment: I want to have the plot of the characteristic curves for my typed up lecture notes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a LaTeX site. What I can offer is to generate a plot in which the intersections of the blue lines with the red curves get computed and used. I am pretty sure that my choices for the red curves are off. However, I fail to make sense of the explanations in the linked post. The good news is that if you replace the functions `xl` and `xr` by something more appropriate, the following will still work (unless you distort the curves so much that the intersections do no longer exist).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={ft=0.1;
xl(\t)=0.5*\t-ft*sqrt(\t);xr(\t)=2+0.5*\t+ft*sqrt(2*\t);}]
 \draw[-stealth] (-1,0) -- (5,0);
 \draw[-stealth] (0,0) -- (0,4);
 \draw[red,semithick,name path=pl] plot[variable=\t,domain=0:4,smooth] ({xl(\t)},{\t});
 \draw[red,semithick,name path=pr] plot[variable=\t,domain=0:4,smooth] ({xr(\t)},{\t});
 \begin{scope}[on background layer]
  \foreach \X in {-1,-0.8,...,-0.2}
   {\path[name path=l\X] (\X,0) -- ++ (4,4);
   \draw[blue,name intersections={of=pl and l\X}] (\X,0) 
   -- (intersection-1) -- (0,0-|intersection-1);}
  \begin{scope} 
   \clip  plot[variable=\t,domain=0:4,smooth] ({xl(\t)},{\t}) -| (-1,0);
   \foreach \X in {-4,-3.8,...,-1.2}
    {\draw[blue] (\X,0) -- ++ (4,4);}
  \end{scope}
  \foreach \X in {2.2,2.4,...,4}
   {\path[name path=r\X] (\X,0) -- ++ (0,4);
   \draw[blue,name intersections={of=pr and r\X}] (\X,0) 
   -- (intersection-1) -- (1,0);}
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I hope this gives you enough mileage to produce the appropriate plots for your lectures.